# Distance formula in java printing NaN -- How do I fix this?

Tags: java, distance

Okay, so I'm using the distance formula to print out the distance between two player objects from inside one of the player objects (With "other"  being another Player object). How can I get it to just print the number without getting a "NaN"?

```
System.out.println("D = " + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - other.x, 2) - Math.pow(-(y - other.y), 2)));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to take the square root of a negative number. Add the squares, don't subtract them.

Also, negating `y - other.y` is unnecessary, though harmless. *value*<sup>2</sup> is the same as (-*value*)<sup>2</sup> for all numbers.

```
System.out.println("D = " + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - other.x, 2) + Math.pow(y - other.y, 2)));
//                                                            ^^^
```

Comment: I guess the players aren't moving around in a hyperbolic space, then :)